# WinSCP stat command says FileNotFound, but it exists when I do ls

Tags: powershell, sftp, ls, winscp, stat

When I run this in PowerShell where $File is just "/path/to/FileName.csv"

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "open sftp://username:password@server/" "stat $File" "exit"
```

I get:

> Can't get attributes of file "/path/to/FileName.csv" No such file or
> directory. Error code: 2 Error message from server (en): FileNotFound:
> The supplied file does not exist.

But if I do a list command, I see the file that I'm trying to stat. The path and file name matches up and is case sensitive.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "open sftp://username:password@server/" "ls /path/to/FileName.csv" "exit"
```

Why is stat not able to see that my file exists?

Comment: Could it be a simple typo? In your ls log, it says Garda_CashReBank_20240111.csv and in your stat log it says Garda_CashRebank_20240111.csv. You have a lowercase b in the second ...

Comment: That makes the logs unreliable. Post actual logs, not fabricated ones.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just switched from using the stat command to WinSCP's .NET assembly and using $session.ListDirectory($File) instead.

Thanks everyone for your input and patience.

Comment: If `ls`/`ListDirectory` works, but `stat`/`GetFileInfo` with the same path does not, then your SFTP *server* is most likely buggy.